# Entity Framework - groupby and timespan calculation

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to calculate total hours of each person in EF.
I can calculate the total hours in MYSQL statement but I have problem with EF.

This is the SQL statement

```
SELECT name, SEC_TO_TIME(Sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ClockOutTime,ClockInTime)))) 
FROM Attendance 
GROUP BY name
```

I want to convert the above statement to EF.

This is what I have so far in controller

```
 var model = db.Attendances
            .GroupBy(a => a.name)
            .Select(g => new AttendanceViewModel
            {
                name = g.Key,
                totalHours = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("seconds",
                                                   g.Select( a=> a.ClockInTime),
                                                   g.Select(a=>a.ClockOutTime))
            }).ToList();
```

The problem that I have is that g.Select( a=>a.ClockInTime) return IEnumrable, and hence I cannot use SqlFunctions.DateDiff direcly. How do I solve this problem? Is there alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select hours for each attendance and do totals calculation after grouping

```
  db.Attendances
    .Select(a => new {
        a.name,
        hours = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("seconds", a.ClockInTime, a.ClockOutTime)
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.name)
    .Select(g => new AttendanceViewModel {
        name = g.Key,
        totalHours = Sum(x => x.hours)
    })
   .ToList();
```

BTW why you named property *hours* if you are calculating seconds?

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you for pointing out the property name also. I wasn't very careful about choosing the name.